# What's the intuitive meaning of the exterior derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I've been studying differential forms and stumbled upon exterior derivatives as a way to prove a differential form is closed. Although I understand the basics to compute the exterior derivative (mainly that dx^dx=0), I don't understand the meaning behind this or why this exterior product appeared in the first place.

Comment: I guess you learn to imagine things in an $n$-dimensional space, first, and then, the intuition comes all by itself.

Comment: Have you learned Green's Theorem? That should show you why the exterior derivative shows up naturally: Why is it $\partial Q/\partial x - \partial P/\partial y$ that shows up?